# Why Google puts 'At' before a date?

Tags: prepositions

Normally we use the preposition 'on' before a date as 'on 20 June 2019'. Why does Google's Blogger site automatically put '**at**' before the dates on which a post is uploaded? A screenshot is given below:

[image]

Comment: Looks odd from that screenshot but you only seem to have captured part of the screen. Could also be that the user determines what goes where you have *May 07, 2019*, and that the designers assumed it would include the time.

Comment: Only Google knows why they chose particular terminology; all we can do is speculate. It is common to record an event such as the publication of a post as a timestamp, however, so as Minty notes, it is likely that Google internally records a date and time down to the millisecond, and time more granular than the day has been hidden from the end user, and the corresponding forms either do not handle this difference well, or were forgotten.